# Automatically instantiate a class in a war file that is newly deployed

Tags: java

Imagine that I want to ensure that class is instantiated upon deployment in Tomcat of the war it is contained in.

For example a class has a static initializer that launches a thread that periodically prints the CPU usage. I need this class to start monitoring as soon as the Tomcat loads the war.

Is there a way to do this without having to call a Servlet that has a reference to this class so the ClassLoader loads it and the static initializer is executed?

Comment: Use a servlet context listener to do that job. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I thought about that too, but I just wonder if there are callbacks like `onExplode` or something, I like the question!

Comment: The life-cycle of the application starts too late for that. If you need to do stuff that early, maybe you should embed the container.

Comment: Hi Ernest, your solution works fine for me. If you create a reply instead of a comment, I'll set it as valid. Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373784/automatically-instantiate-a-class-in-a-war-file-that-is-newly-deployed#comment87763740_50373784), you can use a servlet context listener to do that job. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808918/1073529) shows how to implement the class.